# Rings in which $l_R(a) = Rb$ and $Ra = l_R(c)$ for each $a\in R$

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative semiprime ring with $1_R$.  Suppose that $R$ satisfies the follwoing property:   For each $a\in R$, there exist $b,c \in R$ such that $l_R(a) = Rb$ and $Ra = l_R(c)$, where $l_R(x)=\{r\in R:ra=0\}$.  Rings satisfying this property include: Regular rings, that is,  if 
$aba = a$ then $l_R(a) = l_R(ab) = R(1 - ab)$ and $Ra = Rba = l_(1 - ba)$, with a similar computation on the right.   Also/and  uniserial rings of finite length.

My question is the following:

(1) If $R$ satisfies the property above, does every ideal $I\subseteq R$ satisfy the same property?

(2) Does the quotient ring $R/I$ satisfy the property too?

Comment: I don't even understand for sure what 1) is supposed to mean for "every ideal."  Maybe "for every ideal $I$, there exists $b,c$ such that $l_R(I)=Rb$ and $I=l_R(c)$?"  Every ideal has a cyclic annihilator and $I$ is an annihilator of an element?

Comment: Yes, my question is whether we can extend the property to every ideal $I$ of $R$.  More especially, if we treat each ideal as a ring itself.

Comment: Btw, a commutative semiprime uniserial ring of finite length is just a field...

Comment: Thank you, then no ideals.  So the property extends